# React Native Debugger doesn't run on my Windows 10

Tags: windows, react-native, react-native-debugger

My problem is my React Native Debugger version 10.1 doesn't run on my Windows 10.

I already tried other versions and files but still no luck. I run reactnativedebugger.exe or application still doesn't open. There will be a display of "Installation" after that nothing happens.

Is there any installation? or anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The React Native Debugger version 0.10.1 currently doesn't work with Windows 10.

Try version 0.9.14 or React Native Debugger, the latest version that can be run on Windows.

[React Native Debugger v.0.9.14](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/releases/tag/v0.9.14)